# gorm golang with multiple has one

Tags: go-gorm

I'm having trouble finding the right annotations for multiple has one which reference the same table. something like this:

```
type Pet struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name string
}

type PetOwner struct {
    gorm.Model
    LargestPet *Pet
    SmallestPet *Pet
    AllOthers []*Pet
}
```

Does anybody know what annotations and what explicit id fields would allow this to work?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got this working as follows:

```
type PetOwner struct {
    gorm.Model
    LargestPetID uint
    LargetPet *Pet `gorm:"foreignKey:LargestPetID`
    SmallestPetID uint
    SmallestPet *Pet `gorm:"foreignKey:SmallestPetID`
    AllOthers []*Pet
}
```

and then loading the data as follows:

```
var petOwner PetOwner
db.Joins("AllOthers").Joins("SmallestPet").Joins("LargestPet").Find(&petOwner)
```

If you want to access from the pet for which owner it is the largest pet, you can modify the pet definition as follows:

```
type Pet struct {
    gorm.Model
    ...
    LargestPetOf *PetOwner `gorm:"foreignKey:LargestPetID"
}
```

and then load this with a `.Join("LargestPetOf")`